# Register sent mails

Tags: node.js, email, nodemailer

I'm using a web interface I've done to send mails.
These mails are sent using Nodemailer 2.6.4.

When I login to my roundcube webmail, I want the mails sent using this interface to be shown in "sent messages" section.

Is it possible to do it and how ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't think you can - nodemailer is just an SMTP client, so the receiver (your webmail) is just going to get these mails like any other inbound mail.  It is not like you are using an IMAP client to read/write directly into the folder structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it simply with node-imap.
If someone wants an example, I could post it here.